# Sum top 10 values in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column with about 60 data points that I need to sum the top 10 values of in VBA.  I tried using

```
WorksheetFunction.Sum("LARGE('Sheet1'!A1:A" & lRow & ",{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10})")
```

but it gives me a run-time error.

Also, this is just a test code.  My final code will involve pulling the top 10 values and summing them from one workbook and entering that number into another workbook.  I'm not sure if that changes anything but thats my intention.

Comment: Instead of `WORKSHEETFUNCTION` you can use `EVALUATE` as `Evaluate("=SUM(LARGE('Sheet1'!A1:A" & lRow & ",{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}))")`

Comment: Thanks that worked great!  Sorry for not thanking earlier but I've been away for the last few days.

Comment: I am running into a problem now since I have some #Value and #N/A in a few cells.  Any suggestions?  Should I start a new thread?

Comment: Nevermind, I replaced LARGE function with AGGREGATE and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `Sum`-function, you should use the `SumProduct`-function...

Simply use the following code (if you want to use it in vba evaluate it as a string with the `Evaluate`-function)

`=SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(rng,ROW(INDIRECT('1:N'))))`

with your Range as rng and the amount of entries (in you case 10) as N

Answer (score 0):

In mycode mySum is result.

```
Sub test()

    Dim mySum As Double
    Dim lRow  As Long, i As Integer

    lRow = 12
    With WorksheetFunction
        For i = 1 To 10
            mySum = mySum + .Large(Range("a1:a" & lRow), i)
        Next i
    End With
    Debug.Print mySum
End Sub
```